# A direcitve placed within another directive's link() method does not render

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning angular, and having understood the scoping in directives, I started to be more ... daring, shall I say. I want to render a table nested within another table's cell, where both the tables are generated by two independent directives with different scoping.
Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jared_t83/Y8LjY/
Here's the link method in question:

```
link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
  $scope.property = "scopingTest2.link() - won't overwrite parent"
  var html = element.html(),
    text = [
      'scopingtest2 - new scope, prototipically inherited from the parent',
      '<table>',
      '<tr><th>key</th><th>value</th></tr>',
      '<tr>',
      '<td>Nested table should be here: <br><div scoping-test1></div></td>',
      '</tr>',
      '<tr>',
      '<td>$scope.property</td>',
      '<td>', $scope.property, '</td>',
      '</tr><tr>',
      '<td> $scope.$parent.property </td>',
      '<td>', $scope.$parent.property, '</td>',
      '</tr><tr>',
      '<td> $scope.__proto__.property</td>',
      '<td>', $scope.__proto__.property, '</td>',
      '</tr></table><br>'
    ]
  element.html(html + text.join(''));
}
```

Lines that should render the nested table are:

```
      '<tr>',
      '<td>Nested table should be here: <br><div scoping-test1></div></td>',
      '</tr>',
```

but instead a rendered table I see the literal above.
What am I doing wrong? How to achieve what I want?
I appreciate your time,
Regards
Jared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I get it now. the

```
element.html(html + text.join(''));
```

is a jqLite function which simply puts the passed text on the target element.
To make do what I want to do I need to use the 'template: ' property of the angular directive.
Silly me :)